# How to Evaluate Derivatives in the Form $f'(x^n)$ and $f'(nx)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Please help me with evaluating this derivative:
Given $f(x)=x^3$, find $f'(4x)$. When attempting to evaluate, I did this: $$f'(4x)=\frac{d}{dx}f(4x)=\frac{d}{dx}(4x)^3=3(4x)^2(4)=192x^2$$
Since the end result is clearly not $f'(4x)$, someone said I should have divided by four by I'm not sure why. Also what is a general method for evaluating derivatives where a function is defined but the derivative requested is $f'(x^n)$ or $f'(nx)$

Comment: $(f(4x))'\neq f'(4x)$

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the Theorem called Chain Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x)=3x^2\Rightarrow f'(4x)=3(4x)^2=48x^2$

Comment: So I should have evaluated $f'(x)$, and then inputted $4x$ for $x$?

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. This will work for any such alteration of $x$ in the brackets, correct?

Comment: you are welcome. yes

Comment: I guess that using the chain rule, if you take the derivative of $f(4x)=(4x)^3$ you get $3*16*4x^2=192x^2$ - What do you think?

Comment: then it will be $(f(4x))'$

Comment: @RaziehNoori, thx for your reply. It would be nice if you can point me to any source that show the reason for the difference between the two forms.

Comment: see for calculating $f'(....)$ let $f'=g$ then for example how do you calculate $g(1)$ or $g(1+\pi)$.. you just change $x$ with $1$ or $(1+\pi)$, do not you?

Comment: @NoChance but for $(f(4x))'$ in fact you have composition of two function $f$ and $4x$  that you have to use chain rule. you can search chain rule in net and see some example it will help you to have a better view. (sorry for weak English)